# Jenkins-Traub algorithm to find the zeros of a multiple-variable polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, roots

The Jenkins–Traub algorithm for polynomial zeros is a fast globally convergent iterative method published in 1970 by Michael A. Jenkins and Joseph F. Traub.

The published algorithm, e.g. https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=355643, deals with  polynomials of a single variable.  I wonder whether the algorithm has never been applied on multivariate polynomials. I do not find any of such kind of applications in the literature.

My question is: What are the difficulties for finding roots of a  multi-variable polynomial? In other words, why you can apply Jenkins-Traub on $f(x)=x^2 - 1$ but not on $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2 - 1$. If I understand correctly, a key step of Jenkins-Traub is to iteratively divide the underlying polynomial by (x-r) where r is a root. I felt that you could do polynomial division on multivariate polynomials as well for the purpose of root-finding. I probably misunderstood something somewhere.

Comment: `multi-variable polynomial root-finding` It's not clear what you are asking. Suppose the "*multi-variable polynomial*" were $\,x^2+y^2-1\,$, then what would you expect a "*root-finding algorithm*" to return?

Comment: @dxiv I have rephrased it. Thanks.

Comment: My question still stands from the previous comment: "*what would you expect ...?*".

Comment: @dxiv I would expect a root-finding algorithm to return a root. For univariate polynomials over reals, it should return a real number (maybe in the form of a floating-point). For multivariate polynomials, it should return a vector of reals, or floating-point numbers, of the underlying dimensions. Does this reply to your comment? Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, no, it's still not clear. I can see that you accepted an answer already which (correctly) states it's not possible, but the point of my comment was that the question itself is ill-posed. `For multivariate polynomials, it should return a vector of reals` What would that "*vector*" look like in the case of $\,x^2+y^2-1\,$, for example?

Comment: For the case of $x^2+y^2 -1$, a root would be (1,0), or (0,1), or whatever makes $x^2+y^2=1$. Ah I see, you were saying that a two-degree polynomial has an infinite number of roots!

Comment: @dxiv I appreciate the way you guide me to the answer. It is actually more helpful than reading a well-written solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No chance. Solving for the roots of multivariate polynomials is a completely different beast from the univariate case.

For one thing, a multivariate polynomial will typically be zero on entire curves, and not just at isolated points (consider dxiv's $x^2+y^2-1$ for instance). So usually one seeks to reduce *systems* of polynomial equations, rather than just looking at one equation.

There are some computational techniques for solving such systems, based on constructing Groebner bases. These techniques are extremely expensive and, as far as I know, not nearly as widely used as single-variable solvers like Jenkins-Traub. In practice when finding only a single root is required, (quasi)-Newton methods are used.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "reduce systems of polynomial equations",  do you mean reduce multvariate polynomials to univariate polynomials? How would that work?

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental fact behind the construction of Jenkins-Traub, as well as some other methods like Durand-Kerner and Bairstow, is the fundamental theorem of algebra, that the set of roots corresponds to a complete, unique factorization of the polynomial into linear factors, or linear and quadratic factors if restricted to real coefficients.

For Jenkins-Traub CPOLY, the factorization
$$
P(X)=(X-\alpha)\bar H(X)
$$
is interpreted as an eigenvalue equation
$$
X\cdot \bar H(X)=\alpha\bar H(X)\pmod{P(X)}.
$$
Then linear algebra methods are applied, here variants of the shifted inverse power iteration, primarily to improve the coefficient vector of $\bar H$, with the root approximation improving as a consequence.

Weierstraß-Durand-Kerner is based on the full factorization, starting with some random product and improving all factors, and thus the roots, simultaneously. (Which turns out to be a multivariate Newton method with all properties and consequences.)

Polynomial systems do not have a similar factorization. The conceptually closest idea is the decomposition into irreducible components. But, as far as I know, such a decomposition is the result of a full analysis of the system, not a simplification in the solution process similar to the deflation strategy in the univariate case.

---

In contrast the Newton method, Halley's method etc. are primarily based on function values and derivatives in one point and the resulting low-degree approximation of the function close to this point and its roots. This all generalizes nicely to higher dimension, at least in concept. There is still a difference in global convergence.

Comment: Hello Lutz, can you eleborate more on the last paragraph? Is there a good source for this?

Comment: What claim in particular? The first sentences just summarize the basic working principle. For the last sentence look at Newton fractals and similar pictures for these methods. For polynomials the whole place is filled, you get convergence from any point, even if it is not to the closest root. Next compare to Newton fractals for non-polynomial functions like the cosine. Already you get that convergence happens only close to the real line, close to the roots. A relatively small distance away you get divergence.

Comment: In more than one variable this gets worse, the region of quadratic convergence around the solutions gets smaller and the set of points from where the method reaches one of the solutions, with quasi random jumps, also gets smaller. That is why globalization methods such as homotopies exist. And why genetic algorithms, as a form of a systematic random search, have a chance to be competitive.

Comment: Yes what I am looking for is a source on bivariate  floating point polynomial solver. All I can find is solver for systems of equations.

Comment: If you have 2 polynomials in 2 variables, then compute the resultant of them to reduce to a univariate situation. So if you eliminate Y you get a polynomial in X. Find numerical solutions, insert into first polynomial to get a univariate polynomial in Y, find numerical solutions, confirm with second polynomial which are the actual solutions. This is not optimal, one can use algebraic tricks to make the lifting procedure, the reconstruction of Y, automatic. Another approach is to use homotopy from a full factorized system to the given system.

Answer (score 0):

If one allows complex solutions also, you could take all but one of the variables constant and use one of the root finding algorithms for polynomial in a single variable over the field of complex numbers.